# Cant get Exceptions & Dispose() to work in this method

Tags: c#, exception, firebird

I have the following function which reads from a firebird database. The Function works but does not handle exceptions (Required).

```
public IEnumerable<DbDataRecord> ExecuteQuery(string Query)
{
    var FBC = new FbCommand(Query, DBConnection);

    using (FbDataReader DBReader = FBC.ExecuteReader())
    {
        foreach (DbDataRecord record in DBReader)
            yield return record;
    }
}
```

Adding try/catch to this function gives an error regarding yield.  I understand why I get the error but any workround I've tried has resulted in DBReader being disposed *indirectly via using()* too early or Dispose() not being called all. How do I get this code  to use Exceptions & Cleanup without having to wrap the method or duplicate DBReader which might contain several thousand record?

Update:

Here is an example of an attempted fix. In this case DBReader is being disposed too early.

```
    public IEnumerable<DbDataRecord> ExecuteQuery(string Query)
    {   
        var FBC = new FbCommand(Query, DBConnection);

        FbDataReader DBReader = null;

        try
        {
            using (DBReader = FBC.ExecuteReader());
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Log.ErrorException("Database Execute Reader Exception", e);
            throw;
        }

        foreach (DbDataRecord record in DBReader) <<- DBReader is closed at this stage
            yield return record;

    }
```

Comment: Please show the code that has the error, and what the precise error is.

Comment: What do you mean with 'handle exceptions' ? I don't think this method can or should. Place your catch in the calling code.

Comment: @Henk This Method is in a class whose only purpose to talking to database.  All other methods in the class already handle exceptions so just  trying to maintain a standard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you've got looks fine to me (except I'd use braces round the yield return as well, and change the variable names to fit in with .NET naming conventions :)

The `Dispose` method will only be called on the reader if:

- Accessing `MoveNext()` or `Current` in the reader throws an exception
- The code *using* the iterator calls dispose on it

Note that a `foreach` statement calls `Dispose` on the iterator automatically, so if you wrote:

```
foreach (DbDataRecord record in ExecuteQuery())
{
    if (someCondition)
    {
        break;
    }
}
```

then that will call `Dispose` on the iterator at the end of the block, which will then call `Dispose` on the `FbDataReader`. In other words, it should all be working as intended.

If you need to add exception handling *within* the method, you would need to do something like:

```
using (FbDataReader DBReader = FBC.ExecuteReader())
{
    using (var iterator = DBReader.GetEnumerator())
    {
        while (true)
        {
            DbDataRecord record = null;
            try
            {
                if (!iterator.MoveNext())
                {
                    break;
                }
                record = iterator.Current;
            }
            catch (FbException e)
            {
                // Handle however you want to handle it
            }
            yield return record;
        }
    }
}
```

Personally I'd handle the exception at the higher level though...

Comment: Thanks tried this but wont compile 2 errors "System.Collections.IEnumerator: type used in a using statement must be implicitly convertible to 'System.IDisposable'" & "Cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to 'System.Data.Common.DbDataRecord'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)"

Comment: @Canacourse: I'd assumed this was a generic `IEnumerable`. It sounds like it's not - if you're able to use LINQ, you can use `DBReader.Cast<DbDataRecord>().GetEnumerator()`

Answer (score 1):

This line won't work, note the `;` at the end, it is the entire scope of the `using()`

```
    try
    {
        using (DBReader = FBC.ExecuteReader())
          ;  // this empty statement is the scope of using()
     }
```

The following would be the correct syntax except that you can't yield from a try/catch:

```
    // not working
    try
    {
        using (DBReader = FBC.ExecuteReader())
        {
          foreach (DbDataRecord record in DBReader) 
             yield return record;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Log.ErrorException("Database Execute Reader Exception", e);
        throw;
    }
```

But you can stay a little  closer to your original code:

```
    // untested, ought to work
    FbDataReader DBReader = null;

    try
    {
        DBReader = FBC.ExecuteReader();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Log.ErrorException("Database Execute Reader Exception", e);
        throw;
    }

    using (DBReader)
    {
      foreach (DbDataRecord record in DBReader) // errors here won't be logged
        yield return record;  
    }
```

To catch errors from the read loop as well see Jon Skeet's answer.